# How does Optional covariance work in Swift

Tags: swift, option-type, covariance

How does covariance work for `Optional`s in Swift?

Say I write the following code:

```
var nativeOptionalView: Optional<UIView>
let button = UIButton()
nativeOptionalView = .Some(button)
var nativeOptionalButton = Optional.Some(button)

nativeOptionalView = nativeOptionalButton
```

It compiles and works just fine. However if I define `MyOptional` as

```
enum MyOptional<T> {
    case Some(T)
    case None
}
```

And write the following:

```
var myOptionalView: MyOptional<UIView>
let button = UIButton()
myOptionalView = .Some(button)
var myOptionalButton = MyOptional.Some(button)

myOptionalView = myOptionalButton
```

I get the error:

> error: cannot assign value of type '`MyOptional<UIButton>`' to type '`MyOptional<UIView>`'

I understand why this errors happens with `MyOptional`, what I don't understand is why it doesn't happen with `Optional`.

Comment: I suspect the answer is "compiler magic".

Comment: I was afraid so :/ In that case, considering it's open source, where is that magic?

Comment: Not sure; the codebase is pretty big. Starting point: https://github.com/apple/swift/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=optional+covariant

Comment: If you're interested in learning about it, you might want to ask this question on the swift-dev mailing list.

Comment: I suspect this is the same behind the scenes magic that happens with array covariance, i.e assigning a `Array<UIButton>` to a `Array<UIView>` – these appear to be the exceptions to the invariance of generics.

Comment: There is a nice article written by Alexandros Salazar about Swift variance: https://nomothetis.svbtle.com/type-variance-in-swift

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It doesn't. Swift does not support custom covariant generics for now.

The Swift type checker is per expression, not global (as in Haskell). This task is [handled by](https://swift.org/compiler-stdlib/#compiler-architecture) the Semantic Analysis in [lib/Sema](https://github.com/apple/swift/tree/master/lib/Sema). The constraint system then tries to [match the types](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/swift-DEVELOPMENT-SNAPSHOT-2016-06-06-a/lib/Sema/CSSimplify.cpp#L1152) and special cases of covariance are then handled for [collections](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/swift-DEVELOPMENT-SNAPSHOT-2016-06-06-a/lib/Sema/CSSimplify.cpp#L1674), and [optionals](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/swift-DEVELOPMENT-SNAPSHOT-2016-06-06-a/lib/Sema/CSSimplify.cpp#L1925).

This was a language design decision. You should be able to do everything you need with the built-in collection types and optionals. If you aren't you should probably open a radar.

Answer (score 1):

While I agree that there is probably some "compiler magic" going on, this can be accomplished in your custom implementation by casting the button to a UIView, e.g.

```
var myOptionalButton = MyOptional.Some(button as UIView)
```

or

```
var myOptionalButton: MyOptional<UIView> = .Some(button)
```